# Python Dictionary w/ 2 Keys?

Tags: python

Can I have a python dictionary with 2 same keys, but with different elements?

Comment: What will you get if you request the key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but you can add 2 elements to one 1 key. dictionary = {‘a’, [b,c]}. You would use a list object to have multiple values in a dictionary.

Comment: I believe setting it twice will replace original

Comment: @AramKocharyan: yes, but you can add/append items to it, rather than set: `d['a'].append('c')`. The `dict.setdefault()` method might com in handy. Also have a look at [collections.defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and use  a `defaultdict(list)` or `defaultdict(set)` for example. (and googling - or searching SO - for "python multidict" might get some interesting examples too)

Answer (score 1):

No.

The normal way to do this is with a defaultdict:

```
dd = defaultdict(list)

dd['Your mother\'s key'].append('A')
dd['Your mother\'s key'].append('B')

dd['Your mother\'s key'] #=> ['A', 'B']
```

If this isn't quite sufficient, you can create your own class.

Answer (score -1):

If you want, you can create a list of "pair" tuples, like:

```
thelist = [('foo', 'first_foo'), ('foo', 'second_foo'), ('bar', 'not_foo')]
```

Then you can retrieve something equivalent to `thelist['foo']` with this ugly hack:

```
for pair in thelist:
    if pair[0] == 'foo':
        print pair[1]
```

and get

```
first_foo
second_foo
```